# Error when connecting to the SQL Server 2012

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and there is a problem when I open it it asks me to enter a server name. Which I failed a lot. I tried enter everything that is asked on net when I searched for. Nothing worked it gave me error which the image below shows. `TCP` is `enabled`.

[image]

And when I opened SQL Server Configuration Manager it shows `empty.` When I try to `browse for server` it also shows `completely empty`.

[image]

[image]

What can I do to fix this? . Or how can I create a new `instance` as it says my instance is not found.

I saw lot of posts regarding similar problem but non of them really couldn't address my problem.

Comment: Did you **only** install the **Management Studio**? IN that case you have the GUI - but no **server engine** to actually run against! You need to install the actual **database SERVER engine**, too!

Comment: @marc_s I have it installed in my programs

Comment: Is this question related to programming anyhow (hello?)?

Comment: @okiharaherbst it is related to databases . And if you search for you will find nearly hundreds of questions somewhat similar to this but not this.

Comment: @marc_s my bad I have done it only half . but I had database server engine. Finally I installed it full and there was no problem with server name anymore.

Comment: @Shashi My point is, this SE is for programming related topics. Have you tried asking your question on the DBA SE (http://dba.stackexchange.com/)? I respectfully believe that this is where your question eventually belongs.

Comment: @okiharaherbst I did not know about it. Next time I will. I saw lot of related and same kind questions and answers here. So I also posted. Next time I will post db stuff in to that link. Good you gave that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I haven't installed it properly. I had installed SQL server Management Studio only. Now it is perfectly working after installing SQL server. From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29062) actually. And I browser for `server name` it was there.